# how to recreate Autonumber

Tags: administration

If i create a field autonumber without selecting "Generate Auto Number for existing records" after some days if i want to generate autonumber for existing records without changing present auto numbers, is there possibility?

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot automatically generate new numbers later. This feature is only available when the field is created. If you want to populate the values afterwards, you have to change the field to a Text type, update records with new values (e.g. by using the Data Loader or Import Wizard), then change it back to an auto-number field.